# Symfony2 FOSRestBundle: POST method not allowed, allowed GET

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using FOSRestBundle to build an API. The POST method for my resource is not allowed. Any one knows why. GET requets are accepted though.

```
  ...
  /**
   * @ParamConverter("post", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
   */
  public function postAction(Post $post)
  {
    $person = new Person();
    return $person;
  }
  ...
```

My route config is this:

```
persons:
    type:     rest
    resource: DnD\ApiBundle\Controller\PersonController
```

Comment: Your route is probably configured to only allow GET requests - can you post the route config?

Comment: Can you try with your action name as "postPersonAction" following this doc : http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html

Comment: I just worked it out. this stuff here: @ParamConverter("post",converter="fos_rest.request_body") is not related to the http method, but with the url, and thus is generating a different url:
/persons/post which is not what I want. Documentation for FOS Rest Bundle SUCKS!!!